# How to concatenate data from a many to many table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables having many to many relationship as follows

Departments table

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════╗
║   deptID  ║    DeptName    ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════╣
║   1       ║      abc       ║   
║   2       ║      def       ║       
║   3       ║      ghi       ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════╝
```

the other is
Criteria table

```
╔════════╦════════════════════════╗
║   id   ║     criteria           ║
╠════════╬════════════════════════╣
║   1    ║  number of Employees   ║
║   2    ║  status                ║
║   3    ║  nature of products    ║
║   .    ║  ---                   ║
║   .    ║  ---                   ║
║   .    ║  ---                   ║
║   .    ║  ---                   ║
║   .    ║  ---                   ║
║   .    ║  ---                   ║
║   .    ║  ---                   ║
╚════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

dynamically increasing with many to many relationship in a separate table to give each criteria a value for each department as follows

```
╔════════╦══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ DeptID ║ CrID ║        value        ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1      ║ 1    ║ 20                  ║
║ 1      ║ 2    ║ currently active    ║
║ 1      ║ 3    ║ mechanical          ║
║ 1      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 1      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 1      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 2      ║ 1    ║ 40                  ║
║ 2      ║ 2    ║ paused for transfer ║
║ 2      ║ 3    ║ software            ║
║ 2      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 2      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 2      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 3      ║ 1    ║ 50                  ║
║ 3      ║ 2    ║ heavy duty          ║
║ 3      ║ 3    ║ support             ║
║ 3      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 3      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ 3      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║        ║      ║                     ║
║ .      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ .      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║ .      ║ .    ║ .....               ║
║        ║      ║                     ║
╚════════╩══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

1) how to get this result

```
╔═══════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════╦═════╦═════╗
║  name ║  number of  ║       status        ║ nature of  ║ ... ║ ... ║
║       ║  Employees  ║                     ║ products   ║     ║     ║
╠═══════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════╬═════╬═════╣
║ abc   ║     20      ║ currently active    ║ mechanical ║ ... ║ ... ║
║ def   ║     40      ║ paused for transfer ║ software   ║ ... ║ ... ║
║ ghi   ║     50      ║ heavy duty          ║ support    ║ ... ║ ... ║
║  .    ║   ..        ║ ...                 ║ ... ...    ║     ║     ║
║  .    ║   ..        ║ ...                 ║ ... ...    ║     ║     ║
║  .    ║   ..        ║ ...                 ║ ... ...    ║     ║     ║
╚═══════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════╩═════╩═════╝
```

2) how to get one table as follows

```
╔══════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ name ║                                       notes                                       ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ abc  ║ number of Employees 20 , status currently active , nature of products mechanical  ║
║ def  ║ number of Employees 40 , status paused for transfer , nature of products software ║
║ ghi  ║ number of Employees 50 , status heavy duty, nature of products support            ║
║      ║                                                                                   ║
║ ...  ║ ..................................................                                ║
║ ...  ║ ..................................................                                ║
║ ...  ║ ..................................................                                ║
║      ║                                                                                   ║
╚══════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Is this your homework? What have you tried? Also, please try and reformat your question.

Comment: sorry i did not know how to format but i is done now .. this is resource management system that i am working in :( and i am stuck at this

Comment: can you please put all the tables with their propernames and fields..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)

Do you need this result ? this will required the use of Dynamic SQL as the number of Criteria is unknown or not fixed so the number of columns in the result is not fixed

(2)

```
SELECT d.DeptName,
       notes = stuff(n.notes, 1, 1, '')
FROM   Departments d
       OUTER APPLY
       (
            SELECT ',' + c.Criteria + ' ' + dc.value
            FROM   DeptCriteria dc 
                   INNER JOIN Criteria c      ON dc.CrID  = c.id
            WHERE  dc.DeptID = d.deptID
            ORDER BY c.id
            FOR XML PATH('')
       ) n (notes)
```

Comment: thanx a lot for your reply , i will try it once i get to my PC . for Number (1) yes i need it .. i want to solve this with a crossTab i think but i dont know is crossTab a build-in function in sql server or i need a user developed function..?